# How to make a queryset order_by and after that, make another order maintaining the result of the first one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to sort a queryset result with two columns. 
First, I need to order_by 'date'. Once a have my queries sorted, I need to sort the result, maintaining the first order with order_by 'status'.

Example:

---

```
     date      status
```

---

2019-06-10 15:23:39 20

---

2019-06-12 15:37:31 20

---

2019-06-10 15:18:53 10

---

2019-06-12 15:38:01 10

---

2019-06-12 15:47:09 10

---

2019-06-12 15:36:30 0

---

2019-06-10 16:35:11 0

---

I need the following result:

---

```
     date      status
```

---

2019-06-12 15:37:31 20

---

---

2019-06-12 15:47:09 10

---

2019-06-12 15:38:01 10

---

2019-06-12 15:36:30 0

---

2019-06-10 15:23:39 20

---

2019-06-10 15:18:53 10

---

2019-06-10 16:35:11 0

---

Following the dkango docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by
I'm doing a order_by pass two fields like order_by('-date', '-status')

I'm trying the follow code

```
Measurements.objects.filter(patient=230).order_by('-date', '-status')
```

My result is:

```
         date      status
2019-06-12 15:47:09 10
2019-06-12 15:38:01 10
2019-06-12 15:37:31 20
2019-06-12 15:36:30 0
2019-06-10 16:35:11 0
2019-06-10 15:23:39 20
2019-06-10 15:18:53 10
```

I need the following result:

```
         date      status
2019-06-12 15:37:31 20
2019-06-12 15:47:09 10
2019-06-12 15:38:01 10
2019-06-12 15:36:30 0
2019-06-10 15:23:39 20
2019-06-10 15:18:53 10
2019-06-10 16:35:11 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate to the date of the `DateTimeField` first. We can do this with [**`TruncDate`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate):

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Measurements.objects.annotate(
    date_date=TruncDate('date')
).order_by('-date_date', '-status')
```

The `Measurements` objects that originate from *this* queryset, will have an extra attribute `.date_date` that truncates the `date` up to the date (so the time is `0:00:00` then).

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot Willem, you are amazing.